# Unable to package IOS application in new Appcelerator studio?

Tags: ios, titanium, publish, appcelerator

I have installed in accelerator studio. the problem I'm facing is distribution of app by ad-hoc profile.

When i click on publish > distribute  profile. Choosing provision profile , certificate etc. 
Everything is green tick. Clicked on Apply button then i click on package.

A wizard comes and disappears . No progress shown. I don't know where my package or IPA is saved ??

please help.

Comment: No errors in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't build apps on trial plan.
Check your plan at https://billing.appcelerator.com/